# Setting path to ./src in Webpack4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, config, webpack-4

Just getting started with building my own webpack config. I've looked around but cant seem to find it. How can I set the import path to start at root (src)?

```
- src
--components
---content
----Content.js
--constants
---example.js
---index.js
```

If I wanted to import a constant file to my component I'd have to take the `../../constant` however I would like to just do `./constants`

```
import { EXAMPLE } from "./constants"
```

Currently this is my resolve:

```
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
```

But I am getting an error of cant resolve `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './constants'`

Comment: Look here [resolvealias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I did thats where I got modules from unsure if its the correct one so that all imports start at src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the alias:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }

import { EXAMPLE } from "src/constants"
```

Answer (score 0):

use resolve.alias

```js
  resolve: {
    alias: {
       @: 'src'
    },
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
```

then

```js
import { EXAMPLE } from "@/constants"
```

the . represents the current path